# Operate on every list item *except* matching item in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I'm trying to write a function to calculate an odds ratio given a string that matches one index in a pandas series associated with a mean value. I want to find the value that matches the string, perform a calculation on that. And then take the average of every value in the pandas series that DOES NOT match the string and perform a calculation there. WhatI have

```
def ratio(m, series):


     Numerator = [series.Value[str.contains(motif)].mean()] for motif in series.index
     Denominator = [series.Value[str.contains(motif, case = False).mean()] for motif in series.index

    ratio = numerator/denominator

    return ratio
```

Not familiar with pandas series and hacing a lot of trouble.

Comment: please provide sample input data and sample output data

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
def ratio(m, series):

     Numerator = [series.Value.loc[series.index == motif].mean()] for motif in series.index
     Denominator = [series.Value.loc[series.index != motif].mean()] for motif in series.index

    ratio = numerator/denominator

    return ratio
```